# How to route a workflow with webservice in IBM Maximo?

Tags: maximo

We are using Maximo 7.6.0.8. We need to route a workflow with RESTAPI json services. It can be with ROUTEWF action, or custom java class/automation script.

I was searching web for weeks but find nothing :(

Does anyone know how Maximo route a workflow? What is behind ROUTEWF action? And how can I manually start ROUTEWF action? Or how can I copy what ROUTEWF action do?

Comment: This may help- https://bportaluri.com/2014/01/how-to-launch-workflow.html

Comment: Thx @Maximo.Wiki, but this is just start and stop workflow. I'm looking for routing workflow.

Comment: I don't have a proper answer for you, but IBM's JSON REST API documentation has some sections devoted to interacting with workflow. https://developer.ibm.com/static/site-id/155/maximodev/restguide/Maximo_Nextgen_REST_API.html#_interfacing_with_the_workflow_engine

Comment: Can you provide more detail on what you’re trying to achieve?