# Is it possible to continue existing maximo workflow instance from automation script

Tags: workflow, maximo

In our PR program in maximo, we have a workflow that will route the PR to other team for approval. but the approval process is from email that we create outside of maximo. I would like to know is it possible to continue the workflow instance from automation script?

Right now I create the automation script like this

```
assignmentSet = mx.getMboSet("WFASSIGNMENT",ui);
assignmentSet.setWhere(" WFASSIGNMENTID = " + str(mbo.getLong("WFASSIGNMENTID")));
assignment = assignmentSet.moveFirst();

if(assignment.getString("ASSIGNSTATUS")=="ACTIVE" and NEXTNODE > 0):
    wfstackSet = mx.getMboSet("WFCALLSTACK",ui);
    wfstackSet.setWhere(" WFID = " + str(mbo.getLong("WFINSTANCEID")));
    wfstack = wfstackSet.moveFirst();
    if (wfstack.getInt("NODEID")==mbo.getInt("NODEID")):
        wfstack.setValue("NODEID",NEXTNODE,2L);
    wfstackSet.save();
    wfstackSet.close();
    
    assignment.setValue("ASSIGNSTATUS","COMPLETE", 2L);

assignmentSet.save();
assignmentSet.close();
```

This automation script is only change the workflow maps, but not creating another assignment. Can someone tell me if there's a missing mbo that i need to update in order the workflow to continue to next node? Thank you.

Comment: Your question is quite similar to another question asked previously that didn't receive an answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66413410/how-to-route-a-workflow-with-webservice-in-ibm-maximo

With that in mind, you might receive more possible solutions if you consider helping others on Stack Overflow first then use some of the reputation points you gain to place a bounty on your question:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty

Comment: I'm not currently able to try out the automation script you provided but a couple of points come to mind.  What you're trying to achieve can probably be done either by:

1. Setting the correct values in the correct workflow related mbo's to complete the current workflow assignment and move on to the next node.
2. Finding the correct package, class and method(s) in the Maximo API to use in your automation script that are provided by IBM to perform the same.

Your script attempts #1 & possibly either isn't successful in setting the correct values to the desired mbo's...

Comment: ... (which you could determine by automation script logging and SQL queries against the database) or isn't doing what Maximo does when this is performed via the user interface (perhaps other mbo's are involved).  My guess would be Maximo is doing more than just setting the node id for the entry in the call stack & setting the assignment to complete like in your script but you'd probably have to trace the database session while completing an assignment in the application to confirm exactly what changes are made to which tables.

Comment: Alternatively you may be able to find another way of doing what you're looking to achieve in the methods available here or elsewhere in the Maximo JavaDocs: https://api.maximo.wiki/psdi/workflow/WorkflowDirector.html

Comment: @Maximo.Wiki yes I already try the first option. passing the correct node value into WFCALLSTACK. the Workflow is already update, but it not creating a new assignment if the next node is assignment node.

Comment: After you've set the current assignment status to "COMPLETE" and saved the set are you able to retrieve the next assignment & print the status of it to the log to see if that maybe needs to be updated also to initiate it?  Through printing to the log and perhaps using some of the methods in the link I provided https://api.maximo.wiki/psdi/workflow/WorkflowDirector.html like getAssignment, setAssignment and others you may be able to figure out the next step.

Comment: Also have you tried using the "completeWorkflowAssignment" methods  https://api.maximo.wiki/psdi/workflow/WFInstanceRemote.html#completeWorkflowAssignment instead of manually setting the status of the assignment to complete?  It seems like those methods do more than you're doing (just changing assignment status) because they require you to pass in the assignment, an action and a memo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank to @Maximo.Wiki. I found a solution from your link
we can continue the workflow using automation script like this

```
assignmentSet = mx.getMboSet("WFASSIGNMENT",ui);
assignmentSet.setWhere(" WFASSIGNMENTID = " + str(mbo.getLong("WFASSIGNMENTID")));
assignment = assignmentSet.moveFirst();
MXServer.getMXServer().lookup("WORKFLOW").completeAssignment(assignment, "APPROVE  PR", 1);
```

or rejecting it like this

```
MXServer.getMXServer().lookup("WORKFLOW").completeAssignment(assignment, "REJECT PR ", 0);
```

but with this, it will failed if you put ManualInput node in the workflow, to solve this I add another field in the object